# Perform a split on AttributeResource tag

Tags: javascript, websphere-portal, wcm

I have a `WCM` `HTML` component, and the value stored inside `[AttributeResource attributeName="myKey" separator=","]` is a comma separated `String`.
When rendered on its own, I get the following output on my `HTML` page ..

```
8,9,10,10.5,11,11.5,12,13
```

However, when I try to split it on `,`, it only gives me the first element i.e `8`
How can I split this properly?

```
<script>
var keySplit = String([AttributeResource attributeName="myKey" separator=","]).split(',');
alert(keySplit);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used a `hidden` `input` element to temporarily store values ..

```
<input type="hidden" id="myKeyTemp" value="[AttributeResource attributeName="myKey" separator=","]" />

<script>
var arrayOfValues = document.getElementById("myKeyTemp").value.split(',');
</script>
```